# text in div not going to next line

Tags: php, html, css

for some reason the text in my div doesn't go to the next line, i've tried several different css elements which don't seem to work.... word-wrap:break word, just jumbles the letters...

what i want is for one there is an extra word it goes down to the next line like it's supposed to

this is the div it's in

```
    #top7 {
        width: 150px;
        height:auto;
        margin: 5px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        word-wrap:break-word;
     }
```

text that it's in

```
#p6 {
   font-family: Myriad Pro;
   margin: 1px;  
   font-size: 22px;
   background-color:#540f45;
   padding: 5px 5px 3px 4px;
   margin:4px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
}
```

here is the php function that retrieves the data from the database

```
<p id='p6'><?php echo "<a href='' "</a>"; ?></p>
```

this is all wrapped in these two id's

```
body {
   background:#603e4f;
   display: block;

}

#foursquare {
    background-color:#603e4f;    width: 290px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the  php code in your question. Try just adding an actual space in the echo code after each one. I wonder if it's ignoring the wordbreak because the data is being generated dynamically.

Comment: `<p6><?php echo "<a href='' "</a>"; ?></p6>` looks wrong.

Comment: i've already tried that however nothing happens, also added &nbsp's in the php code it all stays on the same line!

Comment: i deleted what was in the <a href''> because it wasn't relevant to the question, however it seems to work, so i don't think it's wrong?

Comment: do you have a live link?

Comment: just a random element i made i suppose i use it in different places.

Comment: @KiaDull and you expect that to work in a browser?

Comment: You can't invent elements this way. Replace your `<p6>` with a *real element*. HTML is an actual defined specification, where elements have meanings. It exists for a reason. We also can't hope to help you without seeing your HTML. Please add your markup to the question.

Comment: okay i changed it, still receiving the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a proper class and get rid of the p6 element. Obviously you'd use your database generated HTML. I just used your values as an example for the fiddle. Also since you're wrapping the elements in a p tag anyway the word break is pointless unless you expect data to be too long for a single tag. Paragraphs break to a new line automatically.

```
<div id="top7">
<p class="six"><a href="#">CSC110</a></p>
<p class="six"><a href="#">MATH100</a></p>
<p class="six"><a href="#">HINF130</a></p>
<p class="six"><a href="#">CSC110</a></p>
<p class="six"><a href="#">HINF200</a></p>

</div>​

.six {
  font-family: Myriad Pro;
  margin: 1px;  
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color:#540f45;
  padding: 5px 5px 3px 4px;
  margin:4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/5crqT/

Comment: why are they going to the next line, how do i have them so they are on the same line?

Comment: They're going to a new line because p tags do that as I edited in, if you want them on the same line change the p to span. However if you do that your spacing still forces them to one line each because the element is too small to hold two on one line. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/5crqT/1/ Now on that fiddle change the top7 width to 250 and you'll get more than one on a line.

Answer (score 2):

There's no white space in the generated code, add some between elements (and **not** `&nbsp;`)

```
<p6 id="a2"><a href=http://classm8.net/retrieveclasslist.php?className=CSC130>CSC130</a></p6><p6 id="a2"><a href=http://classm8.net/retrieveclasslist.php?className=MATH100>MATH100</a></p6><p6 id="a2"><a href=http://classm8.net/retrieveclasslist.php?className=HINF130>HINF130</a></p6><p6 id="a2"><a href=http://classm8.net/retrieveclasslist.php?className=HINF200>HINF200</a></p6>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment's i've tried this several of times, still rendering the same error.

Comment: The wordbreak CSS would have fixed that if the element were right.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "display:flex" with word-wrap.

```
#top7 { 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:flex;
}
```